# Saved job searches no longer accessible

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I've tried four different browsers (Chrome and Firefox under linux, and Firefox and Safari on MacOS). None seem to show a means of accessing the job searches I've saved.

**Chrome under linux**
[image: Chrome under linux]

**Firefox under MacOS**
[image: Firefox under MacOS]

Workaround: save any new search and then, before the green popup/tooltip goes away, click on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you very much for reporting this. We'd intended to hide one of the options in the nav bar at the top but accidentally hid the whole thing! Should be back now.